# How can I add a column of one data frame to another based on the nearest identifier?

Tags: python, pandas

Problem:

1. I have a data frame `foo` that contains measurements and a `common_step` column, which contains integers indicating when each row was measured.
2. I have a second data frame that also contains a `common_step` column and a `bar_step` column. It translates between the two integer steps.
3. I would like to add `bar_step` as a column to `foo`. However, the `common_step` values of both data frames are not aligned.
4. Thus, for each row in `foo`, I would like to find the row in `bar` with the nearest `global_step` and add its `bar_step` to the `foo` row.
5. I have found a way to do this. However, the solution is very slow. This is because for every row in `foo`, it searches through all rows in `bar` to find the one with closest `global_step`.

```py
foo.sort_values('common_step', inplace=True)
bar.sort_values('common_step', inplace=True)
def find_nearest(foo_row):
  index = abs(bar.common_step - foo_row.common_step).idxmin()
  return bar.loc[index].bar_step
foo['bar_step'] = scores.apply(find_nearest, axis=1)
```

Questions:

- How I can add the closest match for `bar_step` to the `foo` data table with sub quadratic run time?
- Moreover, it would be ideal to have a flag that chooses the row with the closest but *smaller* `global_step`.

Comment: have a look at [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

Answer (score 0):

As @QuangHoang suggested in the comment, [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) does this. Moreover, the second data frame should contain no other columns to not interfere with existing columns in the first one:

```py
foo.sort_values('common_step', inplace=True)
bar.sort_values('common_step', inplace=True)
bar = bar[['bar_step', 'common_step']]
foo = pandas.merge_asof(foo, bar, on='common_step', direction='backward')
```

The `direction` parameter specifies whether to use the nearest lower match, nearest higher match, or nearest match considering both directions. From the documentation:

> - A “backward” search selects the last row in the right DataFrame whose ‘on’ key is less than or equal to the left’s key.
> - A “forward” search selects the first row in the right DataFrame whose ‘on’ key is greater than or equal to the left’s key.
> - A “nearest” search selects the row in the right DataFrame whose ‘on’ key is closest in absolute distance to the left’s key.